# How to add table border to word docx using python docx

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I'm trying to create a word document using docx module of Python. However I am unable to add table border to it like in image (need to increase width of table border).

[image]

My code is as below:

```
from docx import Document
doc=Document()
table=doc.add_table(rows=13,cols=5,style="Table Grid")
doc.save("my_doc.docx")
```